# "Synthetic" instead of "man-made"?

Tags: discussion, moderation, editing

A [question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/11301/is-it-possible-for-coronavirus-or-sars-to-be-man-made) on Bioinformatics SE is about the possibility of coronavirus having been engineered in the lab and the question title includes the phrase "man-made", which, in my opinion, is an example of sexist language use.

Before editing the post, I wanted to double check if "synthetic" would provide the same nuance as "man-made" in the context of this question. Would there be any other word that could be used instead of "man-made"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either "synthetic" or "human-made" would seem to be reasonable edits in my mind and both would maintain the nuance. "Synthetic" sounds better to my native-speaker ears, for whatever that's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed "man-made" is not appropriate. "Synthetic" sounds cool, but "genetically engineered" is more accurate.

The question is about conspiracy theories. In my opinion its the same "logical" as the "creationists" vs. "evolutionists" (I'm a theist BTW). The problem with conspiracy theories is that its "new" every time, but its the same analysis disproves it.